# How can image buffer pixel data be accessed for iPhone app development?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, image

I'm just now starting iOS application development and am interested in how one might access image pixel data/addresses in the iPhone camera image buffer space, or any allocated buffer space for that matter. I am very unfamiliar with just about all iOS devices and do not have much of an understanding of how flow and storage works on something like the iPhone. I am experienced with C/C++ using several computer vision packages, such as OpenCV, and am really only familiar with the methods introduced in that manner of development. Would the iPhone camera buffer (or some other storage) be accessed by direct pixel/address references? What about any sort of handle(s) for accessing this information?

Advice and insight on is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `CGBitmapContextCreate(&outputBuffer, Width, Height, 32, (32 / 8) * Width, ColourSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);`  Not sure you can access its internal buffer directly and modify it but I know that will give you a copy of all the pixels.

Comment: A little more information about what you're trying to do would be helpful. Do you want to apply real-time image processing to the image coming from the camera? Or are you simply trying to allow the user to take a picture and manipulate it? Or something else?

Comment: @Brandon copying is fine, even though it is most likely slower then direct access. And yes I am actually interested in applying both real-time and still photo manipulation from the camera.